# How can I access the processed files in FilePond using React?

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I'm using FilePond to upload files manually in react but the uploaded files are the unprocessed ones (without the watermark) which is visible in the preview,
the FilePond component :

```
<FilePond
ref={ref}
files={imageFiles}
onupdatefiles={setImageFiles}
allowMultiple={true}
maxFiles={15}
allowReorder
dropValidation
name="files" /* sets the file input name, it's filepond by default /
labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or Browse'
//FileTypeValidation plugin
allowFileTypeValidation
labelFileTypeNotAllowed="File of invalid type"
imagePreviewMaxFileSize="6MB"
acceptedFileTypes={["image/"]}
//FileSizeValidation plugin

allowFileSizeValidation
minFileSize="100KB"
maxFileSize="6MB"
labelMaxFileSizeExceeded="File is too large"
labelMaxFileSize="Maximum file size is {filesize}"
//
allowFileMetadata
//
allowImageTransform
imageTransformClientTransforms
imageTransformCanvasMemoryLimit

fileMetadataObject={{
markup: [
[
"rect",
{
left: 0,
right: 0,
bottom: 0,
height: "100px",
backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)",
},
],
[
"image",
{
right: "10px",
top: "10px",
width: "60px",
height: "60px",
src: logo,
fit: "contain",
},
],
],

onpreparefile: (file, output) => {
console.log(output);
// nothing is logged
},
}}
```

/>

in the upload function i access the files using:

```
        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPics; i++) {
      let file = await ref.current.getFile(i).file
}
```

how can i access the processed files?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.